# Emoji shrink on mobile safari ( and UIWebView )

Tags: javascript, ios, css, font-size, emoji

This is a question for both objective-c programmers and HTML/CSS/Javascript programmers

When I try to put Emojis on my website with a large font via CSS it works fine on my laptop but when I view it on my iPhone's browser the emoji shrinks but the rest of the text stays large.

Go here on a laptop: http://jsfiddle.net/yfvuX/

Then go there on an iPhone...

See the difference?

How can I fix this? Either in my UIWebView (Objective-C) or on the website itself (HTML/CSS/Javascript)

Comment: I tried using the font-face "apple-color-emoji"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emojis won't scale beyond 16px font-size on IOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702013/emojis-wont-scale-beyond-16px-font-size-on-ios-7)

Comment: @mahaltertin This question was asked 9 months before that question? I'm not familiar with the S/O "duplicate" policy. There aren't negative connotations associated with being a "duplicate" question are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me when I set the font to Apple Color Emoji like this:

```
font-family: 'AppleColorEmoji';
```

But in my opinion the icons don't look good at huge sizes.

Comment: Font-Family worked for mobile safari! Thankyou so much!!!!!

http://jsfiddle.net/yfvuX/5/

Comment: no longer true for iOS7, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702013/emojis-wont-scale-beyond-16px-font-size-on-ios-7